# httpd (apache2) permission error on fedora 20

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, fedora

I am trying to configure a custom DocumentRoot in apache. Despite I followed all the tutorials I found i couldn't get it to work... Here's the error:

(DocumentRoot must be a directory)

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since dom 2014-04-06 17:37:00 ART; 2s ago   Process: 14072 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 14068 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS
-DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 14068 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Status: "Total requests: 7; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

abr 06 17:36:59 lilo systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server... abr 06 17:36:59 lilo httpd[14068]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 120 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: abr 06 17:36:59 lilo httpd[14068]: DocumentRoot must be a directory abr 06 17:37:00 lilo systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE abr 06 17:37:00 lilo systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. abr 06 17:37:00 lilo systemd[1]:
```

And here's my httpd.conf

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/home/nico/public_html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
#<Directory "/var/www">
<Directory "/home">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/nico/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I executed the command `chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/nico/public_html` and nothing happends.

Here are the prermissions, etc...

> [root@lilo nico]# ls -laZ /home/nico/public_html drwxr-xr-x. nico nico
>
> system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 . drwx--x--x. nico nico
>
> system_u:object_r:file_t:s0      ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by disbling SELinux for apache only:

> semanage permissive -a httpd_t